# Understanding the code for calculating the 95% confidence interval of AUC using bootstrapping

Tags: machine-learning, python, auc, confidence, bootstraping

It's really embarrassing, but I lack statistical knowledge. I would like to find the confidence interval for AUC at 95%. Actually, I got the code from here(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52373318/how-to-compare-roc-auc-scores-of-different-binary-classifiers-and-assess-statist)... but I don't understand if the code is correct.
I know there's no such thing as a free lunch... but I've tried applying Bootstrap principles to my code and have no idea.

My question is how to use the training_test_split method in Python to split the data into X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, and then apply bootstrapping

I would really appreciate it if you could tell me the code.